# Is there a Yum Option that Creates an Error if a Package is Missing?

Tags: yum, configuration

I am using a set of local yum repositories and trying to install a set of packages from those repos. I noticed that when one of the packages on the command line does not exist, Yum just prints out that it was not found and goes along its merry way.

Can I make Yum quit when this happens? Is there some other Yum utility that I can use to give it my repos and my packages and tell me if there is a problem?

```
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=myrepo --nogpgcheck \
   --installroot=/var/some/place/test install \
   abasdfasfeafseasfeasef bash coreutils utils-linux

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package **abasdfasfeafseasfeasef** available.
No package **utils-linux** available.

<snip>

Complete!
```

I am calling Yum from another script and don't appear to have a way to tell if the packages that I installed are **really** installed.

Answer (score 18):

Modern versions of yum (yum-3.4.3-133.el7+, [ticket](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274211)) provide two options that should help with this use-case:

> **skip_missing_names_on_install** If set to False, 'yum install'
> will fail if it can't find any of the provided names (package,
> group, rpm file). Boolean (1, 0, True, False, yes, no).
> Defaults to True.

> **skip_missing_names_on_update** If set to False, 'yum update'
> will fail if it can't find any of the provided names (package,
> group, rpm file). It will also fail if the provided name is a
> package which is available, but not installed. Boolean (1, 0,
> True, False, yes, no). Defaults to True.

Source: [man-pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html)

Usage:

`yum --setopt=skip_missing_names_on_install=False <commands-here>`

Comment: This could do with some extra explanation around it and perhaps a pointer to the Yum manuals as housed at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/yum.conf.5.html but it does seem to solve the problem perfectly.

Comment: If you want this `yum` option to always be set for all user on the entire system you can modify your system level `yum.conf` see `man yum.conf`. For a system that is used 100% for building containers this option should be the default IMO to ensure your containers have all the listed items in your `yum install` commands.

Answer (score 4):

Try using dnf instead of yum, it will fail if a package isn't available the way yum used to.  On CentOS you can install it via:

```
yum -y install epel-release && \
yum -y install dnf
```

Then on a missing package you'll get an error:

```
dnf -y install foobar
Error: no package matched: foobar
```

Comment: Your first snippet gives another answer on its own: just use `yum -y install foo && yum -y install bar && ...` -- yum install will fail if it it's given just 1 package and it can't install that package

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about yum, but you can ask whether a package is installed using `rpm -q my_package ...`.  It will exit with failure status if any of the packages are missing.

```
$ rpm -q abasdfasfeafseasfeasef bash coreutils utils-linux
package abasdfasfeafseasfeasef is not installed
bash-4.1.2-9.el6_2.x86_64
coreutils-8.4-19.el6.x86_64
package utils-linux is not installed
$ echo $?
1
$ rpm -q bash
bash-4.1.2-9.el6_2.x86_64
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: In my situation, I know that the package is not installed because I am installing into a local directory (`--installroot` option). The problem is that the package doesn't exist in the repository and yum doesn't care :(

Comment: How about `rpm --root=/var/some/place/test -q ...`?