# yum install multiple packages requiring all for success

Tags: centos, yum

On centos 7 (docker), I see `yum install` command with several packages succeeds even if some are not found.  This is nasty for scripting :-(

(in this example `golang` not found because I didn't add EPEL repo)

```
[root@1ec73c6c476b /]# yum install golang nano
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.interhost.net.il
 * extras: centos.interhost.net.il
 * updates: centos.interhost.net.il
No package golang available.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nano.x86_64 0:2.3.1-10.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                    Arch                                         Version                                             Repository                                  Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 nano                                       x86_64                                       2.3.1-10.el7                                        base                                       440 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 440 k
Installed size: 1.6 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
nano-2.3.1-10.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                           | 440 kB  00:00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : nano-2.3.1-10.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                   1/1 
  Verifying  : nano-2.3.1-10.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                   1/1 

Installed:
  nano.x86_64 0:2.3.1-10.el7                                                                                                                                                                  

Complete!

[root@1ec73c6c476b /]# echo $?
0
```

It only exits 0 if all specified packages are missing:

```
[root@1ec73c6c476b /]# yum install foo
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.interhost.net.il
 * extras: centos.interhost.net.il
 * updates: centos.interhost.net.il
No package foo available.
Error: Nothing to do

[root@1ec73c6c476b /]# yum install golang foo
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.interhost.net.il
 * extras: centos.interhost.net.il
 * updates: centos.interhost.net.il
No package golang available.
No package foo available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

According to https://access.redhat.com/solutions/321603, the latter behavior is new in RHEL 6, per this changelog: https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/blob/master/ChangeLog#L3749-L3762

> ... If *all* package(s) are "not found", yum turns the message "Nothing to do" into an error (returns 1, atm).  ...thus:
>
> 1. `yum install -y a b && echo worked`
>       This will echo "worked" if *either* a or b is installed after yum finishes, but tries to install both.
> 2. `yum install a && yum install b && echo worked`
>      This will echo "worked" if both are installed (and if a is not available, b will not even try to be installed).

But presumably, a single `yum install a b` is faster and in complex cases better at dependency resolution than `yum install a && yum install b` (?)

Q: Is there any flag/config to install many packages in one yum invocation, requiring *all* to be found for success?

Comment: duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165326/is-there-a-yum-option-that-creates-an-error-if-a-package-is-missing, https://serverfault.com/questions/694942/yum-should-error-when-a-package-is-not-available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `skip_missing_names_on_install` yum configuration option to false can fix this issue and allow installing multiple packages with a single `yum` command while still failing if any one of them is missing.